# how to get the state attached to the controller with ui-router?

Tags: angularjs, angular-ui-router

I have the following routing configuration

```
angular.module('myApp',['ui.router']).config(function($stateProvider, $urlRouterProvider){
     console.log('configuring'); 

     $urlRouterProvider.otherwise('/first/second');

     $stateProvider
        .state('first', {
           'url' : '/first',
           'template' : 'hello first <div ui-view=""></div>', 
           controller: function( $state){
             console.log($state); // does not print what I expect
           }
         })
         .state('first.second', {
            'url' : '/second',
            'template': 'hello second', 
            'params': { 'foo' : 'bar' }
         });
});
```

Available as plunkr: http://plnkr.co/edit/v33jK5xJkLQlE9dGUPqX?p=preview

I expect the console to show state `first`. 
However, it prints state `first.second`.

What am I doing wrong?
How can I get the state I want?

Why do I need this? I would like to reuse the same controller in 2 nested states but get a different behavior depending the substate it belongs to.

Comment: `$state.current` is always pointing on a current state and is not unique for every controller (acts like singleton)

Comment: @MichaelRadionov - is there any way to make it work? maybe without $state?

Comment: Make what work?...you haven't outlined a problem

Comment: @charlietfl - I think I have. I want to get the state I am expecting. The solution should support reusing the same controller. It should print different states.

Comment: How are we supposed to figure out what you are trying to do from one log statement that is correct regardless of your expectations? You may think you have outlined your issue but you haven't

Comment: I guess @guymograbi wants to print a state, which declares a controller in config, to be able to use one controller for multiple routes and to decide what to do in controller depending on state.

Comment: @charlietfl - how would you change my question to clarify that. I have added the line `how can I get the correct state?`. I am open for suggestions to help clarify the question.

Comment: But it is the correct state. this is sounding like an X-Y problem. You can't bend the framework to meet your expectations, need to change approach to match framework

Comment: @charlietfl - do I need to bend the framework to get what I want? I have no idea.. that's why I am asking. Changed the phrasing from `correct` to `the state i want`.

Comment: It's just not clear what you are trying to do at a higher level using only a parent controller and no controller on child states of that parent

Comment: @charlietfl - ok, added some more info. I want to reuse a controller in 2 different nested states. the controller should behave differently based on the sub-state it is defined in.

Comment: can look at `$state.current.parent`

Comment: @charlietfl - seems like a hard coded solution to me. what if I had 10 nested states, each with a controller.. they will all return one before last.

Comment: Using  a `resolve` might help your problem. Parent states always resolve before child states and resolve of parent is also passed to child